# Finding the most probable value from the MCMC sampler output

Tags: python, statistics, mcmc, pymc

I am relatively new to PyMC, and I have a quick question regarding the output from the MCMC sampler.  I would like the find the most probable value (maximum of the posterior) of my variables as found by the MCMC sampler.  Is there a quick way to do this?  Presumably the variable values at the maximum of the posterior as found by the MCMC sampler could be substantially different from those found by PyMC's MAP methods.

Thank you to the developers for providing PyMC.  It is extremely useful for my work.  This question has also been posted to the PyMC google group.

Comment: You're guaranteed that `numpy.mean(model.my_variable.trace[:])` will asymptotically approach the MAP value of `my_variable` as your MCMC chain runs infinitely long.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** As Ahmed Fasih points out, I misread the question. His advice in the comment of the question is the way to do it =)

---

That functionality is built into PyMC. The class `MAP` in the main pymc namespace accepts an array of pymc variables (or a `Model` class), and exposes a `fit`method.

```
map = mc.MAP(model) #or [var1, var2, .. ]
map.fit()
```

then all the pymc variables will be set the the maximum aposterior.

Comment: Cam, though op used the phrase "MAP", pymc.MAP isn't what they want: they want to use MCMC's outputs ("Presumably the variable values at the maximum of the posterior as found by the MCMC sampler could be substantially different from those found by PyMC's MAP methods").